# How to change mouse cursor on window forms edge

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor

I have set Maximize and Minimize size property in my windows form to restrict the increasing or decreasing the form, but when I move my cursor to the edge of form it changes to "<-->" this shape. I do not want this cursor on the edges. It should remain the same as on the full form.

***How can i restrict or change the mouse cursor icon on edges of window form?***

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting the `MaximumSize` and `MinimumSize` properties on your form, change the `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedSingle`. That will prevent your users from changing the size of the form, and prevent the mouse cursor from changing to the "resizing" style cursor.